# Why does using an attribute instead of a method provide such a significant boost in Python speed

Tags: python, regex, performance

I've been experimenting with a class that does pattern matching. My class looks something like this:

```
class Matcher(object):
  def __init__(self, pattern):
    self._re = re.compile(pattern)

  def match(self, value):
    return self._re.match(value)
```

All told, my script takes ~45 seconds to run. As an experiment, I changed my code to:

```
class Matcher(object):
  def __init__(self, pattern):
    self._re = re.compile(pattern)
    self.match = self._re.match
```

A run of this script took 37 seconds. No matter how many times I repeat this process, I see the same significant boost in performance. Running it through cProfile shows something like this:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 46100979   14.356    0.000   14.356    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
 44839409    9.287    0.000   20.031    0.000 matcher.py:266(match)
```

Why on earth is the match method adding 9.2 seconds onto the run time? <strike>The most frustrating part is that I tried to recreate a simple case and was not able to do so. What am I missing here?</strike> My simple test case had a bug! Now it mimics the behavior I am seeing:

```
import re
import sys
import time

class X(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._re = re.compile('.*a')

  def match(self, value):
    return self._re.match(value)

class Y(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._re = re.compile('ba')
    self.match = self._re.match

inp = 'ba'
x = X()
y = Y()

sys.stdout.write("Testing with a method...")
sys.stdout.flush()
start = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
  m = x.match(inp)
end = time.time()
sys.stdout.write("Done: "+str(end-start)+"\n")

sys.stdout.write("Testing with an attribute...")
sys.stdout.flush()
start = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
  m = y.match(inp)
end = time.time()
sys.stdout.write("Done: "+str(end-start)+"\n")
```

Output:

```
$ python speedtest.py 
Testing with a method...Done: 50.6646981239
Testing with an attribute...Done: 35.5526258945
```

For reference, both are *much* faster with pyp, but still show significant gains when running with an atribute instead of a method:

```
$ pypy speedtest.py 
Testing with a method...Done: 6.15996003151
Testing with an attribute...Done: 3.57215714455
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you bother to wrap this in a class.  Is it just to cache the compiled pattern?  It seems like overkill.  Doing `Matcher = re.compile` instead of creating this class would have the same effect, no?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski this class actually has a lot more functionality. I'm only showing one, peformance affecting, piece. It'd be more useful, in this case, if it simply returned True or False. I have actually tried substituting a few different pattern matching algorithms in place of the regex.

Comment: I don't see any properties in your code...

Comment: For those wondering, what @kindall means to express is that, in Python, `properties` and `attributes` refer to different things. Whereas in many languages, the distinction is fuzzy or even meaningless, Python reserves the word `property` for a dynamic language feature that allows one to transparently use getters, setters, and deleters. An `attribute`, what I am actually using above, refers to a simple static object member.

Comment: I was also mislead by your use of the term 'properties'.  Not trying to be obnoxious, but given that you're asking a question about Python specifically and that you acknowledge using the term 'properties' is misleading in a Python context, why would you not edit your question to use the less misleading terminology?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably mostly the overhead of the additional function call.  Calling a Python function is relatively expensive performance wise, because of the need to set up an additional stack frame, etc.  Here is a bare-bones example that demonstrates similar performance:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("f()", "g = (lambda: 1); f = lambda: g()")
0.2858083918486847
>>> timeit.timeit("f()", "f = lambda: 1")
0.13749289364989004
```

There is also the additional cost of doing two extra attribute lookups inside your method: looking up `_re` on `self`, then looking up `match` on that `_re` object.  However, this is likely a smaller component since dictionary lookups are pretty fast in Python.  (My `timeit` example above shows pretty poor performance even when there is only one extra name lookup in the double-call version.)

Comment: (+1) Nice answer -- better than mine :).

Comment: And it's not just the function call. As `dis` will confirm, there are actually several bytecode operations even for simple delegation. Those have to be interpreted.

Comment: Can the vm not optimize this in any meaningful way automatically? I am not sold on the idea of exposing regex.match directly, but that's a huge performance hit that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @davemankoff A tracing JIT compiler inlines code like this for breakfast, so give PyPy a try. But CPython, which I assume you mean by "the vm", cannot optimize this. It's a simple interpreter -- a rather optimized one, but still an interpreter.

Comment: @davemankoff: It's difficult to optimize in general because of Python's dynamic nature.  For instance, you could later do `self._re = someOtherObject`, and then `self._re.match` would no longer be the same as directly calling match on the regular expression object.  [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) does do this by tracing actual execution paths and optimizing them, but it may not be suitable for a real application since it doesn't work out of the box with Python extensions written in C.

Comment: @BrenBarn Maybe I'm nitpicking, but a good deal of the C API is supported and numerous C extensions are working, and Cython support is being worked on (and apparently it's already somewhat functional). Yes, a number of large-name libraries are missing, but "doesn't work" is a tad strong.

Comment: @delnan: I'm not saying it doesn't work, just that it doesn't work right out of the box.  The PyPy website says: "PyPy has alpha/beta-level support for the CPython C API, however, as of 1.9 release this feature is not yet complete. Many libraries will require a bit of effort to work, but there are known success stories."  I think it's fair to say that means using C extensions doesn't work out of the box.  A given C extension *might* work just fine, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: @BrenBarn That's true. In fact, even extensions which work beautifully most likely have to be re-compiled. I just didn't want to leave "doesn't work ..." standing in the room without elaboration.

Comment: @delnan I just tested in pypy. Interestingly, both are _much_ faster, but using a property is still 2x faster. I'll update my original question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

The first version is an extra function call each time. That incurs some overhead.